# Change Pantheon-Files Connect to server SSH port number

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

In Freya, I often mount server file systems through the "Connect To A Server" dialog. I almost always use SSH for this, which has the default port number of 22 of course. I do not use standard ports, so I would like to change this number that appears by default. I'm sure there is a conf file somewhere that would be simple enough to edit with a simple word search. Anyone have any knowledge on this?

Comment: There isnt a config file in Files for this but you could try bookmarking the server - this might save the port in the address

Comment: I want to mark this as sovled/closed but there is no "check" icon, what am I missing here? This happened before and I remember finding it after a while, but the how to shows a green check and I do not see this.

Comment: I have put my original comment as an answer so you should be able to close it.

Comment: @DroWnThePoor, the checkbox is under the voting numbers on the answer

Answer (score 1):

There isnt a config file in Files for this but you could try bookmarking the server - this might save the port in the address